# Add string to array C (pointers)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals

Hello everyone here below i have some code that intialisize an array with 4 elements but there is space for 50 elements.

Now i want that i can manually add some elements to the array but it doesn't work for me can somebody help me? like here i want to add Sander to the 5th element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

char *arr[50] = {"C","C++","Java","VBA"};
char *(*ptr)[50] = &arr;

(*ptr)[5]="Sander";
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("String %d : %s\n",i+1,(*ptr)[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Thx a lot

Comment: Probably because the *fifth* element is at `(*ptr)[4]` :) Remember that array indexing is zero-based.

Comment: oh damm that is stupid of me :p thx

Comment: I have one more question how i can i get the lengt of the indexes that arre used i tried it already with `sizeof` but that wasn't correct

Comment: If you have another question, post another question, not a comment. This is a Q&A site, so use its facilities.

Comment: Ok i will do :)

Comment: @Sandeerius All the uninitialized elements will contain `0`, so you can loop through the array until you find `0`, incrementing a counter as you go.

Comment: I solved it like this `for ( i = 0; i<50 && ptr[i]; i++ )` and it works for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    char *arr[50] = {"C","C++","Java","VBA"};
    char **ptr = arr;

    ptr[4] = "Sander";

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        printf("String %d : %s\n", i+1, ptr[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Or the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    char *arr[50] = {"C","C++","Java","VBA"};
    char * ( *ptr )[50] = &arr;

    ( *ptr )[4] = "Sander";

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        printf("String %d : %s\n", i+1, ( *ptr )[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

In the both cases the output will be

```
String 1 : C
String 2 : C++
String 3 : Java
String 4 : VBA
String 5 : Sander
```

Comment: what happen with the other 45 slots of memory? Where they allocated (is there such a thing in the stack?).

Comment: @aerijman The array is allocated in the stack, It is an array of pointers that point to string literals that have static storage duration. The elements of the array that were not initialized explicitly are  implicitly set to NULL.

Comment: then NULL elements do not occupy memory?

Comment: @aerijman The array has 50 elements that occupy an extent of a memory in the stack.  The size of the extent is equal to 50 * sizeof( char * ). Only the first 4 elements are initialized by addresses of string literals while others are initialized by zeroes.

Comment: Given `char *arr[] = {"C","C++","Java","VBA"};`, what's the problem with `arr[4] = "Sander";`?

Comment: @aerijman The author of the question did not know how to do the same using pointers.